# ERROR: Not able to resolve navigation_drawer_open in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to build a `Translucent Navigation bar` for my android app. I separately tried developing the task bar and then had intend to include it in my application.

I am not allowed to upload images yet (as I don't have the reputation), therefore here's an example of what I am trying to build for my APP:

[Image Slider example](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-G9HMrmZMctQ/VJ_bFxKuOfI/AAAAAAAAAtU/7aRR8JSJ_Mc/s1600/Screenshot_2014-12-28-14-50-39.png)

I am getting errors in the `MainActivity.java` file.

I get an Error in the following line of code :

```
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
```

Error :

> Error:(48, 79) error: cannot find symbol variable navigation_drawer_open
>
> Error:(48, 112) error: cannot find symbol variable navigation_drawer_close

This is the entire code of MainActivity.java file:

```
package sha.testing_sidebar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String TITLES [] = {"Home","Events","Mail","Blog","Attending"};
int ICONS [] = {R.drawable.ic_home,R.drawable.ericsson_2_png,R.drawable.ic_mqil_hdpi,R.drawable.ic_blog_2,R.drawable.ic_attending};

        String NAME = "Sharang Bharadwaj";
        String EMAIL = "sha.bh91@gmail.com";
        int PROFILE = R.drawable.sha1;

private Toolbar toolbar;

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
DrawerLayout Drawer;

ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mAdapter = new sha.testing_sidebar.MyAdapter(TITLES,ICONS,NAME,EMAIL,PROFILE);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

    Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.DrawerLayout);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,Drawer,toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            //actions upon opening slider
            //presently nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            //actions upon closing slider
            //presently nothing

        }
    };
    //Drawer Toggle Object made
        Drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The error is

Comment: Have you defined those string resources?

Comment: No I haven't defined them in strings.xml . Should I ?

Comment: Oh, no, really, you shouldn't! It can define it by itself, as well as write entire program. You just need to sit back and relax

Comment: My bad for the question. But, do I need to define navigation_drawer_open  in strings.xml ?

Comment: yes you should. Is it your first Android application? Don't you want to learn some basics to avoid such questions in future?

Comment: I have done basic Java but Learning advanced java and at the same time trying to build an Application for my internship.

Comment: You need Android basics in addition to Java basics, not advanced Java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following in your `strings.xml` file

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Drawer Open</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Drawer Closed</string>
```

It should work after that.

Comment: The error is no more. But isn't strings.xml to store the strings which are to be referenced as variables. Why have you declared "navigation_drawer_open"  when it is supposedly a function to draw and withdraw the task bar. Would really appreciate a reply.

Comment: It seems to compile without any errors, but as I run it on the emulator. It gives me a pop up with an error:" Unfortunately, testing_bar has stopped"

Comment: As given in the source code of [`ActionBarDrawerToggle`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.java), String resources must be provided to describe the open/close drawer actions for accessibility services

Comment: And for the other error, please provide more details like the crash log and the code. Can't really help with just an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy/paste this in the strings file

```
<string name="navigation_drawer_open">Drawer Open</string>
<string name="navigation_drawer_close">Drawer Closed</string>
```

they might be there already, if true, both will be underlined in red.
if so erase the existing ones and copy/paste the same two lines.